# Elastic Search + twitter river - how many machines do I need?

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch

I was running an elastic search server along with twitter river to download data from twitter public stream. Recently, I have added around 40 filtered stream rivers which track 40 different keywords relevant for my experience. However, that has caused the server to become considerably slow. When I do a top on the server, it always shows > 100% CPU consumption.

My question is how many machines do I need, for a system like this. The data downloaded per day is of the order of a few GBs. Currently, I am running it on a single 8-core machine (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31280 @ 3.50GHz) with 8GB ram.

Also, now I have around 437 unassigned shards out of total approx 800. I have tried restarting the server many times, but they still don't get allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming elasticsearch is configured to utilize more than default memory machine specs you have listed should be plenty (unless you have really slow disks possibly?) - i have been able to do similar with fewer cores and memory but using ssds for storage with data going to single shard index without replicas (not production data at this point and ok for me to lose).

Have you tried indexing the data into a single shard index with no replicas or maybe a 5 shard index? Not sure why 800 shards on a single node unless you are planning on expanding cluster to many many machines or have other requirements that make this necessary like having to have many indexes. How many indexes do you have on that node?

Also, can you put the 40 keywords in a single filtered stream river - if all data is going to single index that may reduce cpu usage for rivers and should collect same data.

Comment: Yes, removing the indices and creating one index for all 4o keywords did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose for optimal performance and reliability there should should be:

- a **at least one replica per index**
- a few shards to be able to use single DB on a few physical servers

Default config 5 shards / 1 replica seems pretty good, thought for the heavy loaded system that is supposed to be used on a few servers **indexes * number of shards per index * (replicas + 1) should be not less then number of servers for DB** hosting.

And total number of shards in the single node surely should not more than dozens thus it's really better to not use separate indexes for each keyword considering their amount.